# Blue buble for current location on Google Maps not showing

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to make an app, which will be able to show my current location with a standard blue bubble targeting it. I set my release.keystore, use release.keystore to generate SHA1 fingerprint, and get API key. However, when I start my application, Google Maps is available but not my position, although it appear sometimes. Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blue dot appearance depends on your device being able to localize itself.

Make sure you turn on the GPS and have related settings enabled in My location part of Settings app: "Use wireless networks" and "Use GPS satellites".

Comment: Maybe it is because of the release version, but on the debug version it worked fine, and it found mine location instantly.

Comment: I have enabled all that things, and still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
    UiSettings uiSettings = googleMap.getUiSettings();
    uiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

It will show a button, on map when you will click it, it will show your current location, with blue dot.

Comment: Thanks,it worked for ICS 4.0.3, but not for the Samsung Galaxy SII with 4.1 on it. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you using support library ?

Comment: I'm using google_play_services_lib,if you mean that,and I've updated it to the newest version,and still nothing...

Comment: Maps v2 are not supported below API 12 unless you use support library